# How to Access Google Cloud VM from other Google Cloud VM in different region

Tags: linux, linux-networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, local-area-network

Is there any way to Access Google Cloud VM from other Google Cloud VM in different region?
I have seen that one of my US-Iowa 10.121.0.4 while Asia-Japan Region is 10.148.0.5

I was planning to host mysql on only 1 server and use it from other machine and host machine both (which are acting as web server). I thought this because my tables has read and write operations both which require simultaneous syncing of databases.

Can I host somehow access mysql on Asia-Japan? 
I tried accessing Japan machine using the command on US server:

```
mysql -h 10.121.0.4 -u test -p
```

but nothing is working. Even the ping is not happening to 10.121.0.4. 
Not sure what I am missing. I have checked all firewalls access and they are fine.

Logically if everything is on Google Cloud, I should be able to ping any machine and basis authentication I should be able to enter. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't ping internal IP via VM to VM, it is part of a security method of GCP, since it needed a [VPN connection](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpn-dynamic-routes).